# Loading no ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Como faço para adicionar um loading, ao meu ajax? Esse loading começaria quando o ajax fosse iniciado e terminado quando retornasse o resultado. meu code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url + "login/ajaxLogin",
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result)
    }
});

return false;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiramente escolha um gif de seu gosto:
este site tem alguns muitos bons: http://ajaxload.info/

Agora, vamos configurar:

coloque o modal no HTML (este é o elemento que irá aparecer na tela com o "loading..."):

```
<div class="modal"></div>
```

Vamos aplicar os devidos estilos no modal pelo CSS

```
.modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
                url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') 
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
}

/* enquanto estiver carregando, o scroll da página estará desativado */
body.loading {
    overflow: hidden;   
}

/* a partir do momento em que o body estiver com a classe loading,  o modal aparecerá */
body.loading .modal {
    display: block;
}
```

e no JQuery você usa desta forma:

```
$body = $("body");

$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");    },
     ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); }    
});
```

ou no seu caso:

```
    $body.addClass("loading");
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "login/ajaxLogin",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            $body.removeClass("loading");
            alert(result);
        }
    });

return false;
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar isto:

```
$(document).on({

        ajaxStart: function () {                                
            $("#ComponenteLoading").show();                                   
        },
        ajaxStop: function() {

            $("#ComponenteLoading").hide();                    
        }

    });
```

Porém, dependendo do browser (Google chrome, por exemplo) o paralelismo não trabalha muito bem nessa situação, e caso você utilize requisições ajax síncronas, seu 'balão de loading' não será apresentado.

O evento será disparado juntamente com o início da requisição e com isso, o browser 'trava' e não mostra o balão corretamente.

Para que funcione na situação de *ser uma requisição ajax síncrona*, nestes determinados browsers, você terá que interceptar manualmente o ponto correto de mostrar/esconder o balão:

```
$("#ComponenteLoading").show();
$.post("/UrlServico/Teste", function(dados){
        $("#ComponenteLoading").hide();
});
```

Comment: Como ficaria isso se fosse adptado ao meu code?

Comment: O Iago complementou. Só uma ressalva sobre a resposta dele: preencher toda a tela em todo o AJAX não vai produzir uma boa experiência para o usuário caso você tenha várias solicitações AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Creio que este código vá te ajudar.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (){
    //Show loading
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    //Hide loading
})
```