# Evitar "dedo nervoso" change de botão switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um switch button, e quero fazer um post toda vez que ele mudar de true para falso.
Porem preciso evitar que o cara click varias vezes. E consiga apenas fazer a alteração de true para false
depois de ter concluido o post anterior.

Para quem quiser ver minha função hoje é assim:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrbZOg

```js
$(function() {

  $('.switch').on('change', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  margin: 60px;
}
.switch {
  background-color: #bebebe;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.switch.checked {
  background-color: #76d21d;
}
.switch input[type="checkbox"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  left: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.05s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: left 0.05s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.05s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: left 0.05s ease-in-out;
  transition: left 0.05s ease-in-out;
  width: 10px;
}
.switch.checked input[type="checkbox"] {
  left: 38px;
}
.switch input:before {
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #f0f0f0 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fff), color-stop(100%, #f0f0f0));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #f0f0f0 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #f0f0f0 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #f0f0f0 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #f0f0f0 100%);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  content: '';
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -9px;
  width: 26px;
}
.switch input:after {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%, #fff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f0f0f0), color-stop(100%, #fff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%, #fff 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%, #fff 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%, #fff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0f0f0 0%, #fff 100%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  content: '';
  height: 12px;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
}
.switch .icon-ok,
.switch .icon-remove {
  line-height: 28px;
  text-shadow: 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 9px;
}
.switch .icon-ok {
  float: left;
}
.switch .icon-remove {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch checked">
  <i class="icon-ok"></i>
  <i class="icon-remove"></i>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
</label>
<label class="switch">
  <i class="icon-ok"></i>
  <i class="icon-remove"></i>
  <input type="checkbox">
</label>
```

Comment: Porque não da um "disabled" no button quando ele mudar de estado?

Comment: Pode colocar uma 'flag' para ver se ele clicou ou não

Comment: o Post ai que você fala é uma requisição ajax, isso?

Comment: @FleuquerLima depois que o post acontecer, tem que dar um "enabled" no botão para caso ele queira alterar para false por exemplo.

Comment: @adelmo00 isso mesmo ele faz via ajax

Comment: Resovi o problema com o disabled. Mas quem tiver alguma solução com debounce por exemplo, e quiser compartilhar fiquem a vontade.

Comment: Você pode  colocar um loading na tela e esconder o botão on/off. Veja um exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75743/loading-no-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar essas funções aqui:

```
$(function() {

  $('.switch').on('change', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    var input = $(this).find('input');
    input.attr('disabled', true); //desativa o botão

    var data = { name: "John", time: "2pm" }; //seus dados vão aqui

    var jqxhr = $.post('http://suaurl.com', data);

    jqxhr.done(function() {}); //código de sucesso

    jqxhr.fail(function() {}); //código de erro

    jqxhr.always(function() {
      input.attr('disabled', false);
    }); //Sempre vai ser executado depois da promisse

 });

});
```