# Exibir mensagem de sucesso após cadastro ser concluído via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Quero exibir um mensagem como "carregando" enquanto está processando o cadastro e outra com "Cadastro concluído", este é meu código AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:5001/v1/enterprise",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {

        guid = data;


        $(".cad_sucesso").css({
            display: 'block'
        })

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".cad_sucesso").fadeOut();
            $(".processo_sucesso").css({
                display: 'block'
            })
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = "/dataImmobile/DataImmobile/NewImmobile";
            }, 1000);
        }, 3000);

    },
    failure: function(data) {
        alert(data.responseText);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert(data.responseText);
    }
});
```

O que eu to fazendo aqui? 
Exibindo primeiro uma div com uma mensagem 'Carregando', e depois de alguns segundos exibe a div com a mensagem de 'Cadastro concluído', porém não está dinâmico pois eu estou estabelecendo o tempo para exibir as mensagens. 
Como eu pego o tempo dessa requisição?

Comment: tente usar um modal em vez do alert

Comment: veja se esse link te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75743/loading-no-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o evento `beforeSend` para exibir a sua div de progresso e escondê-la no sucesso. A invés do `.css({display: 'block');`você poderia simplesmente utilizar o método `show();`

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:5001/v1/enterprise",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  crossDomain: true,
  beforeSend: function() {
    //Exibe a div de progresso
    $(".cad_sucesso").show();
    
  },
  success: function(data) {

    guid = data;

    $(".cad_sucesso").fadeOut(function() {
      //exibe a div do sucesso após o fadeout do progresso
      $(".processo_sucesso").show();
      
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "/dataImmobile/DataImmobile/NewImmobile";
      }, 1000);

    });

  },
  failure: function(data) {
    alert(data.responseText);
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert(data.responseText);
  }
});
```